# parsing xsd complexType recursively

Tags: c#, recursion, xsd

```
private ElementDefinition ParseComplexType(XElement complexType, string nameValue = "")
        {
            var name = complexType.Attribute("name");

            ElementDefinition element = new ElementDefinition()
            {
                Elements = new List<ElementDefinition>(),
                ElementName = name != null ? name.Value : string.Empty
            };

            foreach (var el in complexType.Descendants().Where(k => k.Parent.Parent == complexType && k.Name.LocalName == "element"))
            {
                ElementDefinition tempElement = new ElementDefinition();
                var tempName = el.Attribute("name");
                var tempType = el.Attribute("type");

                if (tempName != null)
                {
                    tempElement.ElementName = tempName.Value;
                }
                if (tempType != null)
                {
                    var tempTypeValue = tempType.Value.Substring(tempType.Value.IndexOf(":") + 1, tempType.Value.Length - tempType.Value.IndexOf(":") - 1);
                    if (tipovi.Contains(tempTypeValue))
                    {
                        tempElement.ElementType = tempTypeValue;
                        element.Elements.Add(tempElement);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        complexType = GetComplexType(tempTypeValue);
                        element.Elements.Add(ParseComplexType(complexType, tempName.Value));

                    }
                }

            }
            if (nameValue != "") element.ElementName = nameValue;

            return element;
        }
```

Hi so this is a function i use for parsing XSD complexTypes.

This is a xsd schema i use [xsd Schema](http://pastebin.com/KZNCK0yL).
I have problem parsing complexType element at line 14.

It only parses shipTo element, skipping billTo and parsing badly items.

The result is http://pokit.org/get/?b335243094f635f129a8bc74571c8bf2.jpg

Which fixes can i apply to this function in order to work properly?

PS. "tipovi" is list of xsd supported types, e.g. string, positiveInteger....

EDITED:

```
private XElement GetComplexType(string typeName)
        {
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
            string x = "";
            foreach (XElement ele in xsdSchema.Descendants())
            {

                if (ele.Name.LocalName == "complexType" && ele.Attribute("name") != null)
                {

                    x = ele.Attribute("name").Value;
                    if (x == typeName)
                    {
                        return ele;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

GetComplexType finds complexType definition of an element type. For example, for "PurchaseOrderType" (line 10) it returns element at line 14.

Comment: What is the method *GetComplexType* doing? Can you show code?

Comment: See my answer below regarding the skipped billTo. But your code has a more serious issue in that it not can handle the structures and elements it encountes in the XSD. First, your code just ignores elements without a type attribute. For example, look in your XSD at the "Items" complex type. Note that this has an "item" element without type attribute. But that is not enough - the "item" element has as a sole child an unnamed complex type -- your code does not even make an attempt to handle this situation.

Comment: Another problem: Look at the "PurchaseOrderType" complex type. It has an "comment" element, which has neither a "name" nor a "type" attribute. Instead it has a "ref" attribute. Again, the code does not even attempt to handle this case. These two examples should make it very clear that your code still needs some effort to make it working. I would suggest to you to try implementing the handling of the structures and elements which can be encountered in the XSD. If you have **specific** programming problems while doing this, ask us and we will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE: This is only a partial answer as it only explains the issue regarding the skipped "billTo" element. The code as presented in the question has many more issues.*

**The problem regarding skipping of the billTo element**

The `complexType` variable is used in the predicate for the Linq method *Where* in the foreach loop:

```
 complexType.Descendants().Where(k => k.Parent.Parent == complexType && k.Name.LocalName == "element"))
```

This lambda expression **uses** the variable *complexType*, not merely its value.

By assigning another value to *complexType* deep down inside your *foreach* loop

```
complexType = GetComplexType(tempTypeValue);
```

you also change the logic of which elements are filtered by the predicate of the *Where* method in the the *foreach* loop.

**The Fix**

The solution is rather simple: Do not change the *complexType* variable within the *foreach* loop. You could do the call of *GetComplexType* like this:

```
XElement complexTypeUsedByElement = GetComplexType(tempTypeValue);
element.Elements.Add(ParseComplexType(complexTypeUsedByElement, tempName.Value));
```